# Using regex or excel, how to convert a date into a decimal?

Tags: regex, excel

I have an excel file with 200k rows. In one column, approx. 20% of the values show incorrect data.
The problem: the values in the excel should be depicted, for instance, as '1.00' or '2.75'. 
The faulty rows show data as dates. For instance, '1.1.2026' [Day-Month-Year] instead of the correct '1.26', or '1.5.2025' as '5.25', or '1.2.1975' as '2.75'.

Question: how can I use Excel or Regular expression to transform all my faulty rows to being correct?
I have already tried changing the data format to 'Text' or others. Doesn't help (instead, changing the data format to General for '1.2.1975' gives the value '27426', which is incorrect).

Thanks.

Comment: You should have set the data format to text when importing the data to Excel. No regex can help you here. Probably all you need is open a blank sheet and Import data from text with correct settings per column.

Comment: You could try =VALUE( MONTH(A2) & "." & RIGHT(YEAR(A2),2))